# How to write sensor data so seperate text file (Raspberry Pi, Python)

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, lora

I have a pm2.5 sensor attached to a raspberry pi. I got the code working for the sensor but I want to be able to store the values being outputted. I was wondering what I needed to change to be able to write the data to a text file.

Heres my code:

```
import time
import board
import busio
from digitalio import DigitalInOut, Direction, Pull
import adafruit_pm25

import serial
uart = serial.Serial("/dev/ttyS0", baudrate=9600, timeout=0.25)


print("Found PM2.5 sensor, reading data...")

while True:
    time.sleep(1)

    try:
        aqdata = pm25.read()
        # print(aqdata)
    except RuntimeError:
        print("Unable to read from sensor, retrying...")
        continue

    print()
    print("Concentration Units (standard)")
    print("---------------------------------------")
    print(
        "PM 1.0: %d\tPM2.5: %d\tPM10: %d"
        % (aqdata["pm10 standard"], aqdata["pm25 standard"], aqdata["pm100 standard"])
    )
    print("Concentration Units (environmental)")
    print("---------------------------------------")
    print(
        "PM 1.0: %d\tPM2.5: %d\tPM10: %d"
        % (aqdata["pm10 env"], aqdata["pm25 env"], aqdata["pm100 env"])
    )
    print("---------------------------------------")
    print("Particles > 0.3um / 0.1L air:", aqdata["particles 03um"])
    print("Particles > 0.5um / 0.1L air:", aqdata["particles 05um"])
    print("Particles > 1.0um / 0.1L air:", aqdata["particles 10um"])
    print("Particles > 2.5um / 0.1L air:", aqdata["particles 25um"])
    print("Particles > 5.0um / 0.1L air:", aqdata["particles 50um"])
    print("Particles > 10 um / 0.1L air:", aqdata["particles 100um"])
    print("---------------------------------------")
```

Comment: Just as a minor note, try to use f-Strings if the Python version permits. Instead of doing your `%d` things, just do this:
`f"PM 1.0: {aqdata["pm10 env"]} ..."`

Comment: If you normally run your script with `python script.py` and you like the output as it is, you can just run it with `python script.py > results.txt &` If you want to peek at the file while it is growing, use `tail -f results.txt`and then `CTRL-C` to stop tailing it.

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

```
measurement_values = [0.3, 0.5, 1.0]
measurement_strings = [f"Particles > {size}um / 0.1L air" for size in measurement_values]

with open("myfile.txt", "w") as f: 
    # Write block of string
    f.write("Block of string") 
    # Write whole list
    f.writelines(measurement_strings)
```

Comment: Did you mean to include the "f" in [f"Particles >.....

Comment: Yes. This is called an f-string, where instead of using %d and format, you can simply write the variable names into your string in the {}. There are other letters you can put before strings, such as u (I believe unicode), r (raw, for instance if you don't want the \ in filenames to mess up stuff) and likely a few more.

Comment: `f-strings` are great - have a read here... https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/

Comment: I came back to this recently, and (L) was never defined which results in an error.

Comment: Ah yes, the L should indeed be `measurement_strings`, will fix it in post.